# Combination Password Generator

Tags: python, python-2.x

My goal here is to make a program that makes a list of passwords that has no doubles, making an end result of every combination of passwords in a specific area.

```
print "Make sure you have a botnet army for this..."
print "You will need one or this will take about 20+ days to     compile.\n(Depending on your cpu speed and proccessor model)"
r = raw_input("You do realise there are 208+ million combinations to     crack right?\n(Y/N) >>>")

if r == 'Y':
   print "Ok beginning to do this..."

elif r == 'y':
    print "Ok beginning to do this..."

elif r == 'N':
    print "Ok well there is...\nI am beginning to do this..."

elif r == 'n':
    print "Ok well there is...\nI am beginning to do this..."

filename = raw_input('Enter the filename including file extention.\n>>> ')
f = open(filename, 'a')
np = int(input('Enter amount of passwords.\n>>> '))

double = 0  # <---||__The double amount__||
pn = 0      # <---||__The password number||

pass_len = int(input("Enter the password length.\n>>> "))
wordlist = []
# Just to feed it a string to make the first run successful.
#               __________
#               \/\/\/\/\/
#                \/\/\/\/
#                 \/\/\/
#                  \/\/
#                   \/
wordlist.append('H9kl01hU')
doubles = []
da = 0
```

The below is the for loop that runs until all combos are reached

```
for _ in range(np):
    password = (''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase +     string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for i in range(pass_len)))
    for word in wordlist:
        if password not in wordlist:
            pn = pn + 1
            print "Added (%r)\t\tDoubles detected and removed (%r)" % (pn, da)
            f.write(password)
            f.write('')
            wordlist.append(password)
            if pn == np:
                print "All done closing file..."
                f.close()
                break
                exit(0)

            elif pn != np:
                pass

        elif password in wordlist:
            doubles.append(password)
            da = da + 1
            np - 1
```

Comment: In Python, indentation is important. This code is not properly indented, so will not work as expected. Broken code is off-topic at Code Review, please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: It does work i have it running i must of not typed it correctly.

Comment: FIxed it now have you any ideas on how to make this in a new approach ?

Comment: Would you please explain to me what's the point of asking the user if they want to proceed if you then proceed anyways, regardless of the user's answer? Or tell me what is the effect of the `pass` statement. Or a simpler question: did you write this?

Comment: Yes i wrote that also the pass statement is their for readability nothing else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) As mentioned by kyrill, whether intended or not, the program will run the same way *no* *matter* *what* the user enters on the first prompt - the program may print one thing or another, or print nothing at all, yet the code goes further. I would handle the cases N/n and add a behavior for default case.

2) The names of the variables should be clearer, especially the ones that live more than just a few lines. I bet you are going to forget the difference between `pn` and `np` variables in a couple of days. Keep it as is: `password_number`, `number_of_passwords`.

3) Magic constants ought to be moved to constants - you may want to change `H9kl01hU` to some other value later or pass it through to a function in a different module.

4) Storing passwords in list makes little sense - the more passwords you have checked, the more there are collisions. Think how many collisions there going to be before you finish if you need all passwords of some particular length. And every collision is just useless CPU burning. I suggest you sort them or use a search tree to store them.

Comment: Ad 4) How about a set?

Comment: If i removed the list how would i check if the password is a double or not then iv been trying different methods of this for a week now on/off but cannot seem to find any efficient way ?

Comment: If you keep your data in set as suggested by @kyrill, you won't have to check doubles (namely collisions) at all. If you use a search tree, you will still be able to check if a password is already used, but it will take logarithmic time instead of linear (which is a good performance boost in case of lots of passwords).